# How can I manually determine the CodePage and Locale of the current OS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2000

Is there a way that I manually have a user look up the current Codepage and locale of their windows OS? Is there a registry setting that stores that information?

It would also be useful if the technique worked all the way back to Windows 2000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Win32 `GetACP()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318070(VS.85).aspx) works back to Windows 2000 to find the ANSI code page.

The [`GetLocaleInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318101(VS.85).aspx) function works also back to Windows 2000.  Call it with a Locale parameter of `LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT` (or `LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT`, etc.)

If your question is not how you can get this data programmatically, but instead how a non-programmer can look up this info, then you probably want to post the question on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) which is the right spot for questions like that.